# C# ListView Tag Implemented MySql Delete

Tags: c#, listview, tags

I am currently developing a small C# application where I have a sql database.
In my app I created a ListView showing me all the data from my table,
I then gave the user the ability to delete some of these data (by clicking on the desired line(s)),
But I’ve managed to get him to delete one data but not several at the same time, and I can’t find a lot of documentation on that.
I still tried with a foreach loop but nothing to do it takes only the first selected data.
It is certainly a mistake on my part, but I am asking for your help anyway;)

There is my method to create my ListView :

```
private void chargerListe()
        {
            listeTest.Clear();
            listViewCustom();
            ListViewItem newP = new ListViewItem();

            connectionBDD();
            SqlCommand sqlRequete = new SqlCommand("", SqlServerDB.ConnectionBase);
            SqlDataReader sqlRdr;

            sqlRequete.CommandText = "Select * From Test;";
            sqlRdr = sqlRequete.ExecuteReader();

            while (sqlRdr.Read())
            {
                newP = new ListViewItem();
                string ID = sqlRdr["ID"].ToString();
                newP.Text = ID;
                newP.Tag = sqlRdr["ID"];

                string nom = EncryptDecrypt.Decrypt(sqlRdr["Nom"].ToString(), "MotDePassePasswordPvlImp");
                newP.SubItems.Add(nom);

                string prenom = sqlRdr["Prenom"].ToString();
                newP.SubItems.Add(prenom);

                string majeur = sqlRdr["Majeur"].ToString();
                newP.SubItems.Add(majeur);

                listeTest.Items.Add(newP);

            }
```

And there is my event delete (with a button) :

```
private void bSupprimer_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        connectionBDD();
        SqlCommand sqlRequete = new SqlCommand("", SqlServerDB.ConnectionBase);

        MessageBox.Show("Voulez vous vraiment supprimer les personnes séléctionnés?", "Suppression", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question);

        if(listeTest.SelectedIndices.Count != 0)
        {
            foreach (ListViewItem item in listeTest.Items)
            {

                if (item.Selected)
                {

                    int id = (int)listeTest.SelectedItems[0].Tag;
                    MessageBox.Show("TEST " + id);

                    try
                    {
                        sqlRequete.CommandText = "DELETE from Test where ID =" + id + " ;";
                        sqlRequete.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        listeTest.SelectedItems.Clear();
                        chargerListe();
                    }
                    catch
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("Error with SQL query !", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                    }

                }
            }

        }else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Veuillez selectionner une personne pour pouvoir la supprimer", "Info", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
        }

        listeTest.Refresh();
        initSourceGrid();
        MessageBox.Show("Action effectuée !");
    }
```

As you can see I use the Tag to be able to delete my data in the database according to the ID.
Thank in advance ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you just delete every record in the same DELETE-Statement?
You could do a `foreach` like you did but in it you would create a string for the `sqlRequete.CommandText`.
It could look like:

```
string deleteStatement = "DELETE from Test ";

if (listeTest.SelectedIndices.Count != 0)
{
    foreach (ListViewItem item in listeTest.Items)
    {
        if (item.Selected)
        {
            int id = (int)listeTest.SelectedItems[0].Tag;
            MessageBox.Show("TEST " + id);

            try
            {
                if (!deleteStatement.Contains("WHERE"))
                {
                    deleteStatement += "WHERE ID='" + id + "' ";
                }
                else
                {
                     deleteStatement += "OR ID='" + id + "' ";
                }
            }
            catch
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Error with SQL query !", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }
        }
    }
}
else
{
    MessageBox.Show("Veuillez selectionner une personne pour pouvoir la supprimer", "Info", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
}

sqlRequete.CommandText = deleteStatement;
sqlRequete.ExecuteNonQuery();
listeTest.SelectedItems.Clear();
chargerListe();

listeTest.Refresh();
initSourceGrid();
MessageBox.Show("Action effectuée !");
```